# Deleting final cell row within a cell array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a function that searches for a specific string within my cell array, and if found deletes that row, returning boolean as true if it succeeds and false if otherwise:

```
BookCell = cellstr(find_by_title(TitleString));
Index = strcmpi(CharacterLibrary, BookCell);
IndexRef = sum(Index(:));
if IndexRef == 0
boolean = false;
else
LibraryArray(Index) = [];
boolean = true;
[LibraryCount,~] = size(LibraryArray);
end
end
```

My issue is that when 'LibraryArray' only has one row, it becomes a 1x0 cell array instead of deleting the row as occurs when the array is larger. My present solution is simply to use a conditional for the size of the array, where if it is one the entire array becomes:

```
 LibraryArray = {};
```

Are there any other solutions to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `LibraryArray(Index,:) = [];`, that way you will delete the single *row* rather than the single *column*:

```
C1 = {1};
C2 = {1};
C1(1) = []; % 1×0 empty cell array
C2(1,:) = []; % 0×1 empty cell array
size(C1) % [1 0]
size(C2) % [0 1]
```

Comment: Worked excellently, exactly the kind of simplicity I figured I had missed. Thanks. I had forgotten that linear indexing works in columns, rather than rows, as the array I'm working with is only one column, so it didn't matter.